# Finding minimum value of Max function

Tags: combinatorics, maxima-minima

> Given $7$ non negative reals such that $a+b+c+d+e+f+g=1$ and $$M=\max(a+b+c,b+c+d,c+d+e,d+e+f,e+f+g)$$

What is the minimum value $M$ can take

Weird thing is, this was given in Combinatorics chapter and I can't relate any topic (Pigeon Hole, Permutation & combination and Seive Formula) to this problem. Looks more like inequality problem.

Further, a hint is given which doesnt seem very helpful

> Hint:  Append the four numbers $a,a+b,f+g,g$ to the five given

Comment: What five numbers were given?

Comment: @mvw the number inside max function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately $M\ge\frac{1}{3}$, because $(a+b)+(c+d+e)+(f+g)=1$ the least maximum value of these is $\frac{1}{3}$. If $a=d=g=\frac{1}{3}$ then $M=\frac{1}{3}$ so the minimum value of $M$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: To zero everything except $a, d, g$ is a good choice, it reduces to $M = \max(a, d, g)$. Though I do not see that your argument is a proof for it being optimal.

Comment: $M\ge {\rm Max}(a+b+c,c+d+e,e+f+g)\ge {\rm Max}(a+b,c+d+e,f+g)$. If all of  $a+b,c+d+e,f+g$ strictly less than $\frac{1}{3}$ then $a+b+c+d+e+f+g<1$ contrary to assumption, so they must all be at least $\frac{1}{3}$, hence $M\ge\frac{1}{3}$. I don't know if this is the only optimal choice